# Deactivate Mesh Renderer when not visible by camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In order to save memory, I would like to disable set of mesh Renderers of gameObjects that are not visible by the camera. So far I have the below script:

```
     private MeshRenderer rend;


     void Start()
     {
         rend = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
     }  


     public void OnBecameVisible()
     {
         rend.enabled = true;
     }


     public void OnBecameInvisible()
     {
         rend.enabled = false;
     }
```

`OnBecameInvisible()` is being called but `OnBecameVisible()` is only being called once? Is it because the mesh renderer is off? If so, is there any other solution to get it back on?

Comment: occlusion culling...........

Comment: @BugFinder could you please explain. I am new to the topic of occlusion culling.

Comment: set your objects to to occlusion/oclusee (sp?) static, turn on the culling, this works with dynamically placed stuff too, and see the magic

Comment: Occlusion: Blockage. Culling: Remove. Occlusion Culling: "Remove blocked objects". In other words: if something is not visible do not render it.

Comment: Well after you disabled the Renderer it is impossible for the object to become visible again ;) why do you even need this? Unity anyway should only be rendering the meshes visible to the Camera by default...

Comment: @derHugo it does not. That is the issue. Having too many objects active only makes the performance to lag. So deactivating few mesh renders would boost up the performance.